# Does App Bundles (AAB) automatically use APK Signature Scheme v2?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-app-bundle, android-app-signing

I am reading some Android 11 updates documentation and apparently it is required to implement APK Signature Scheme v2. Does the AAB format do this already?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Android App Bundle is only a publishing format. The mandate of the signature v2 scheme applies to APKs that are installed on the device. When Google Play generates the APKs from the App Bundle, it uses signature v2 scheme (or more recent), so if you publish to Google Play, you're sorted.

Comment: Hi, do you have a source for this?

Comment: Play Signing documentation mentions v4 signing scheme, which is an extension of v2 and v3 schemes. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en-GB